# Spell Checker webservice in InfoPath 2010- Workaround for Spell Checker

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, infopath

Does anyone know how to use

```
/_vti_bin/SpellCheck.asmx
```

in InfoPath form as DataConnection to check spelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function CheckSpelling()   {

SpellCheckEntirePage(‘/_vti_bin/SpellCheck.asmx’, ‘/_layouts/SpellChecker.aspx’);

}